# IBM Cloud User Management API - Invite users - User status doesn't become Active

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried to invite a user to my IBM Cloud account by the REST API.
The user is successfully registered but its status didn't become Active, so that he can't use the account in my IBM CLoud account env.
How can I make the user status Active? When I invited a user by ibmcloud cli, the user is registered and becomes Active immediately without any additional operation.

Has anyone invited a user to IBM Cloud account and succeeded?

I ran the REST API and invited a user to my IBM CLoud account.

I got the response from the REST API.

{"resources":[{"id":"xxxx","email":"myuser@ibm.com","state":"PROCESSING"}]}

I checked the user status many times over 4 hours but its status remains PENDING. it didn't become Active.

```
  "state": "PENDING",
```

I checked by ibmcloud cli. Then the status remains PENDING.

```
$ ibmcloud account users
Getting users under account $MYACCOUNT...
OK
User ID              State     Role
myuser@ibm.com      PENDING   MEMBER
user1@jp.ibm.com   ACTIVE    PRIMARY_OWNER
user2@jp.ibm.com     ACTIVE    MEMBER
```

Invite a user by the REST API

```
curl -X POST \
  https://user-management.cloud.ibm.com/v2/accounts/&MYACCOUNT/users \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{
      "users": [
      {
        "email": "myuser@ibm.com",
        "account_role": "Member"
      }],
      "iam_policy": [
      {
        "roles": [
        {
          "id": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::role:Viewer"
        }]
      }]
    }'
```

CHecked the user status

```
   {
      "id": "xxxx142ad70df5fd5a1f72",
      "iam_id": "BSS-xxxxad70df5fd5a1f72",
      "realm": "BSS",
      "user_id": "myuser@ibm.com",
      "firstname": "",
      "lastname": "",
      "state": "PENDING",
      "email": "myuser@ibm.com",
      "phonenumber": "",
      "altphonenumber": "",
      "photo": "",
      "account_id": "$MYACCOUNT"
    },
```

When I invited a user via the ibmcloud CLI, a user becomes ACTIVE immediately. How can I do the same operation by the API?

Comment: Hi my problem has been solved. Please ignore the question. thanks

Comment: Hi, Adding an answer with details of how this is resolved will help any other user facing a similar issue.